# How to add button (onclick event) on tabs but not switch the panes - semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I want to add a button on top of list of tabs configured with semantic UI. Currently I have 2 tabs which can switch to panes when they are selected and I have third tab - I don't want it to switch when user click on it but rather dispatch an event (to expand the UI) or lets say a alert message. How to achieve this ?

[Current code](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-dhhrfk)

`example.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Label, Menu, Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: { key: 'users', icon: 'users', content: 'Users' },
    render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane>,
  },
  {
    menuItem: (
      <Menu.Item key='messages'>
        Messages<Label>15</Label>
      </Menu.Item>
    ),
    render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane>,
  },
]

const TabExampleCustomMenuItem = () => <Tab panes={panes} />

export default TabExampleCustomMenuItem
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Container, Header, List } from "semantic-ui-react";

import pkg from 'semantic-ui-react/package.json'
import Example from "./example";

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <Container style={{ margin: 20 }}>
    <Header as="h3">This example is powered by Semantic UI React {pkg.version} </Header>
    <List bulleted>
      <List.Item
        as="a"
        content=" Official documentation"
        href="https://react.semantic-ui.com/"
        target="_blank"
      />
      <List.Item
        as="a"
        content=" StackOverflow"
        href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic-ui-react?sort=frequent"
        target="_blank"
      />
    </List>

    {children}
  </Container>
);

// TODO: Switch to https://github.com/palmerhq/the-platform#stylesheet when it will be stable
const styleLink = document.createElement("link");
styleLink.rel = "stylesheet";
styleLink.href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";
document.head.appendChild(styleLink);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <Example />
  </App>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image: Edit semantic-ui-example (forked)]

Comment: You mean like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-51ttf6

Comment: Hi Maniraj , Thanks for answer but I am looking it to make it work on tabs itself not any external button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of controlled state to achieve similar result. Take a look at the following example:

`example.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Label, Menu, Tab } from "semantic-ui-react";

const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: { key: "users", icon: "users", content: "Users" },
    render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane>
  },
  {
    menuItem: (
      <Menu.Item key="messages">
        Messages<Label>15</Label>
      </Menu.Item>
    ),
    render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane>
  },
  {
    menuItem: <Menu.Item key="open">Open</Menu.Item>
  }
];

const TabExampleCustomMenuItem = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Tab
      panes={panes}
      activeIndex={activeIndex}
      onTabChange={(e, data) => {
        if (data.activeIndex === 2) {
          alert(`You've clicked on the "Open" tab!`);
          return;
        }
        setActiveIndex(data.activeIndex);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default TabExampleCustomMenuItem;
```

[image: Edit 74439945]

Comment: Hi @junwen-k , Thanks for answer this works fine but tabs still change though , i tried doing e.preventDefault still its switching the tabs

Comment: @DivakarR Hi, the early return should block the tab change. You should double check your `activeIndex` to make sure that it matches with your special tab button. You can check the code in the Sandbox I've shared in the answer.

Comment: my bad i had missed activeIndex={activeIndex} , this works perfect , Thanks